# Does a fixed penalty notice imply an admission of guilt?

Tags: england-and-wales

Further, does it result in a criminal record?

Comment: Some do, some don't (to both questions) - any particular one on mind?

Comment: It's usually very explicit on such notices if it does or not.

Comment: Thanks for asking, but No, I'm honestly just trying to reach as comprehensive hypothetical understanding of the issue as possible, in particular all of the commonly seen routes to getting - and not getting - a  criminal record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UK, if your car drove too fast or drove over a red light, and you have a UK driving license with less than 12 points, and maybe it’s required that you are a Uk citizen or resident, then you’ll get a letter. (In the other cases, you don’t get away with it but have to go to court which will be more expensive).

That first letter asks if you are the driver, and if not, who the driver is. If you don’t answer or know, you go to court. And after that a second letter is sent to the driver which is often you.

Then you can either pay or go to court. A fixed penalty notice for traffic violation is *not* a criminal conviction. It is an admission of guilt. Actually, some years ago a British government minister and his ex wife went both to jail because *she* had admitted a traffic Offenes that *he* committed.

Comment: Is the same true of FPNs for non traffic related offences?

Comment: Cars don’t “drive too fast” or “over a red light”, the driver does. Unless they are self-driving which are still extremely rare

Comment: Dale, quite obviously cars drive too fast and over red traffic lights. The driver is not known at this point. You get the first letter when _your car_ drives too fast. It's the owner of the car as first contact. The owner should know who the driver was.

Comment: There might be other rules for non-traffic related offences, but I can't remember. I think traffic related is the majority.